# Android Bluetooth Status

Tags: android

I want to make a simple android application that detects if Bluetooth is enabled or not.

I have already made an app to detect if WiFi is on or not using the code shown below.
What I want to know is, how can i use a similar code for Bluetooth.

Code Used for WiFi:

```
ConnectivityManager mycm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    boolean wifi = mycm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();


    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);


    if (wifi){
        tv1.setText("Wifi is connected");
    }

    else{
        tv1.setText("Wifi is not connected");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
boolean hasBluetooth = (mBluetoothAdapter == null);

if(hasBluetooth && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
{
//enabled ON
}
else
{
//Disabled OFF
}
```

Comment: Can I use the "Connectivity Manager" as I have used for WiFi?
BTW, thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: ConnectivityManager answers queries about the state of network connectivity like Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc. not about Bluetooth Status

Comment: It should be: boolean hasBluetooth = (mBluetoothAdapter != null);

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />` also use this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml File

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html